# Ask and store configuration variables during installation of a windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services, app-config, setup-project

I want to set the variables in App.config while the windows service is getting installed.

I have seen many people recommending Link :
http://raquila.com/software/configure-app-config-application-settings-during-msi-install/

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exePath);
```

is not working. Is it a in built code or we need to open and store variables manually?

Comment: What exactly is not working? What have you tried?

Comment: As suggested in link I have created new installer class in the main application (windows service in my case), and the following peace of code in giving compilation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the `System.Configuration` reference to your project?

After doing so, you have to define the following directive:

```
using System.Configuration;
```